# All vs All dot product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I have two 2D numpy arrays `A` and `B` with the following dimensions `(row, cols)`

`A.shape = (3000, 128)` and `B.shape = (5000, 128)`

I wish to take the dot product for each row of A with each row of B. Such as;

```
np.dot(A[0], B[0])
np.dot(A[0], B[1]
np.dot(A[0], B[2]
 .   *  .
 .   *  .  
 .   *  .
np.dot(A[0], B[last]) # last row in B
np.dot(A[1], B[0]) # new row in A
np.dot(A[1], B[1])
np.dot(A[1], B[2])
 .   *  .
 .   *  .  
 .   *  .
np.dot(A[last], B[last]) # last operation
```

Is there a particular name of this operation?

Right now I have two for loops which I guess is pretty slow.

```
all_dots = []
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    for j in range(0, len(B)):
        all_dots.append(np.dot(B[j], A[i]))
```

Am looking for perhaps a native operation in linear algebra that solves this more efficiently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the matrix product of the transpose of B: `A @ B.T`

Comment: Did you mean `np.dot(A[0, :], B[0, :])` etc?

Comment: Does this give all the combinations? I thought there would be more than np.dot(A, B.T) ? @Dan. I want to for each row in A perform the dot product with each row in B. So heaps of combinations.

Comment: @Dan `A[0,:]` and `A[0]` is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Each row of A with each column of B.T is the classic description of a matrix product.  `np.do(A,C) t` (and `A@C) pair the last dimension of A with the 2nd to the last of C.

Comment: A lsbister `A @ B.T` will do all the conbinations you're looking for

Comment: @Dan Thx. So the answer u wrote before with the broadcasting is not relevant?

Comment: Yes I just deleted it. Sorry I confused myself. My initial response of doing a simple matrix product is correct. Test it your self with a simple toy example. Also note you can use `ravel` to flatten the result, but if you leave the result as a matrix, then the position of the matrix tells you which two rows that number is the dot product of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a matrix product. Number of columns of first matrix should be equal to the number of rows in the second

```
np.dot(A, B.transpose())
```

which yields an equivalent of what your code with two nested loops does. Another way is to use a matrix multiplication operator `@` and a shortcut `.T` for `.transpose()`

```
A @ B.T
```

or the `.dot()` method of a numpy array

```
A.dot(B.transpose())
```

Kudos to Dan!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the infamous [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', a,b)
```

Test:

```
a, b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', a,b)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 14,  38,  62,  86],
       [ 38, 126, 214, 302],
       [ 62, 214, 366, 518]])
```

If you want a 1-D array, chain that with a `.flatten()` or `ravel()`:

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', a,b).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([ 14,  38,  62,  86,  38, 126, 214, 302,  62, 214, 366, 518])
```